# Wix Installer - Updating more than one connection string

Tags: c#, wix, installation, windows-installer, connection-string

I have some experience with Wix. Initially I had a config file with one connection string (the first one below) and the installer was working perfectly. Now that I added another connection string I am running into issues. XML:

```
<util:XmlFile Id="leID2" File="[INSTALLFOLDER]Queue.exe.config" Sequence="3" Action="setValue" ElementPath="/configuration/connectionStrings/add[@name='String1']/@connectionString" Value="metadata=res://*/EntityModels.String1.csdl|res://*/EntityModels.String1.ssdl|res://*/EntityModels.String1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=[DBSERVER];initial catalog=[DBNAME];User=User;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" Permanent="yes" />

<util:XmlFile Id="leID3" File="[INSTALLFOLDER]Queue.exe.config" Sequence="4" Action="setValue" ElementPath="/configuration/connectionStrings/add[@name='String2']/@connectionString" Value="metadata=res://*/EntityModels.String2.csdl|res://*/EntityModels.String2.ssdl|res://*/EntityModels.String2.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=[DBSERVER];initial catalog=[SECONDDBNAME];User=User;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" Permanent="yes" />
```

DBSERVER, DBNAME, SECONDDBNAME are all properties being set from a custom user input window. When I install, this is the result in the config file:

```
<add name="String1" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EntityModels.String1.csdl|res://*/EntityModels.String1.ssdl|res://*/EntityModels.String1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=**mydbserver**;initial catalog=**seconddbname**;User=User;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>

 <add name="String2" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EntityModels.String2.csdl|res://*/EntityModels.String2.ssdl|res://*/EntityModels.String2.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=[default from project];initial catalog=[default from project];User=User;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

So the first connection string takes the DBSERVER name properly, but it takes the Second DB name entered. 
The second connection string remains completely unchanged from what I had in my visual studio project. It was not modified.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `XPATH`, you need to set this attribute in your `util:XmlFile` node:

```
SelectionLanguage="XPath"
```

Source:

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/xmlfile.html

**Edit:**

Try this:

```
<util:XmlFile Id="leID2" File="[INSTALLFOLDER]Queue.exe.config" Sequence="3" Action="setValue" ElementPath="/configuration/connectionStrings/add[\[]@name='String1'[\]]/@connectionString" Value="metadata=res://*/EntityModels.String1.csdl|res://*/EntityModels.String1.ssdl|res://*/EntityModels.String1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=[DBSERVER];initial catalog=[DBNAME];User=User;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" Permanent="yes" />

<util:XmlFile Id="leID3" File="[INSTALLFOLDER]Queue.exe.config" Sequence="4" Action="setValue" ElementPath="/configuration/connectionStrings/add[\[]@name='String2'[\]]/@connectionString" Value="metadata=res://*/EntityModels.String2.csdl|res://*/EntityModels.String2.ssdl|res://*/EntityModels.String2.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=[DBSERVER];initial catalog=[SECONDDBNAME];User=User;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" Permanent="yes" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, made the change but still the same result

Comment: There was an issue in the *ElementPath*. Try updating this (I have updated the answer) - this should hopefully fix your problem. You still need the *SelectionLanguage* set to *XPath*

Comment: Excellent, tried it and it works perfectly. I never suspected something was wrong with this because it worked as long as there was one conn string only. Thanks!